# monetdbd: internal error while starting mserver

Tags: monetdb

I am following the MonetDB tutorial but after executing this command:

```
shell> mclient -u monetdb -d voc
```

and inserting the password I receive the following error

```
monetdbd: internal error while starting mserver
```

This is the error in the log file. How can I solve this? Thank a lot!!

```
2016-05-23 08:41:39 MSG voc[1060]: !IOException:mal_mapi.listen:operation failed: binding to UNIX socket file /vagrant/mydbfarm/voc/.mapi.sock failed: No such file or directory

2016-05-23 08:41:39 MSG merovingian[1054]: database 'voc' (1060) has exited with exit status 0

2016-05-23 08:41:39 MSG merovingian[1054]: database 'voc' has shut down

2016-05-23 08:41:39 ERR merovingian[1054]: client error: database 'voc' started up, but failed to open up a communication channel
```

Answer (score 1):

try a `mkdir -p /vagrant/mydbfarm/voc/` as the user who runs MonetDB perhaps?

Comment: Looks like the aptly named @John has not been around for over a year. This answer sounds about right.